# Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on crypto 3.0.0 and Cruise depends on crypto 2.1.3, flutter_driver from sdk is forbidden

Tags: flutter

When I compile my project, it shows this error:

```
 Running "flutter pub get" in cruise-open...
Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on crypto 3.0.0 and Cruise depends on crypto 2.1.3, flutter_driver from sdk is forbidden.
So, because Cruise depends on flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because Cruise depends on flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed.)
```

I have tried each version of `crypto` but still not fix my problem, what should I do to solve it? This is my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: Cruise
description: A RSS article read Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: 0.16.1
  meta: ^1.1.8
  flutter_svg: 0.19.0
  logger: 0.9.4
  marquee: ^1.7.0
  scoped_model: ^1.1.0
  shrine_images: ^1.1.2
  flare_dart: 2.3.4
  flare_flutter: ^2.0.2
  vector_math: ^2.0.8
  collection: ^1.14.0
  package_info: ^0.4.0
  fluttertoast: 7.1.6
  google_fonts: 1.0.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.0
  adaptive_breakpoints: ^0.0.2
  cupertino_icons: 1.0.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  flutter_icons: ^1.0.0
  timeago: 2.0.26
  animations: 1.1.2
  flutter_hooks: ^0.12.0
  share: ^0.6.4+3
  shimmer: 1.1.1
  crypto: 2.1.3
  url_launcher: 5.5.0
  uni_links: 0.4.0
  flutter_html: 1.2.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
  state_notifier: ^0.5.0
  flutter_secure_storage: 3.3.3
  flutter_slidable: "^0.5.5"
  hive: ^1.4.1+1
  #fluwx: ^2.4.1
  pull_to_refresh: 1.6.3
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.5.0
  dio: 3.0.10
  fish_redux: 0.3.4
  hive_flutter:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/hivedb/hive.git
      path: hive_flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  test:
  path:
  args:
  grinder: ^0.8.0
  pedantic: ^1.9.0
  string_scanner: ^1.0.5

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
```

Comment: You can run `flutter pub outdated` to check where the issue lies. https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-outdated

Comment: Have you checked [this article](https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here `crypto: 2.1.3`. You need to update it to the latest version i. e. `crypto: ^3.0.0`.

This should solve your issue.
What happens is that when you use so many packages, some of those packages use some other packages. It may so happen that two or more packages use the same package.

In your case, the package `flutter_driver` uses the package `crypto`. And you yourself are using the package `crypto` but a different version of it. So, it creates an error because you cannot have two different versions of the same package.